# boto3 lambda client create_function using default role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Currently I need to spawn an AWS lambda function programmatically. I do so by using the following piece of code.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id="[FAKE_ACCESS_KEY]",
                        aws_secret_access_key="[FAKE_SECRET_KEY]",
                        region_name="us-east-1")

lambda_client = session.client("lambda")

lambda_response = lambda_client.create_function(FunctionName="MyCoolFunction",
                              Runtime="python3.7",
                              Role="[ARN_TO_MANUALLY_CREATED_ROLE]",
                              Handler="main.handler",
                              Code={"ZipFile":open("lambda_aws.zip", "rb").read()})
```

I was wondering whether or not it is possible to replace `[ARN_TO_MANUALLY_CREATED_ROLE]` with a "default" role id with the minimum number of permissions - so I don't have to manually go into the console and create it.

Comment: You can create a role programmatically too with a check if it does not exist

Comment: @JunedAhsan I have permissions to create `Lambda` functions but not to create `IAM` roles - nor will I be allowed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS doesn't have a "default" role you can use for lambda execution, rather you have to create it as part of your script, or use a previously created role.

That said, they do have a [few](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) managed Lambda Execution policies that you could use, but obviously they are attached to roles which you cannot make.

When I've been confronted with these types of situations I look to see if there is a role I could assume from a source account into the target account to do whatever is needed.  It's sometimes easier to ask a customer to make a role for you to assume ahead of time- then it is to ask them to let you make something in their account.  This allows them to control what you're allowed to do.